# Conda and pre-commit, error: Library stubs not installed for "requests" (or incompatible with Python 3.10)

Tags: conda, mypy, typing, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

### Error message

While using a conda environment and `pre-commit` I receive the error:

```
error: Library stubs not installed for "requests" (or incompatible with Python 3.10)
```

The full error message is:

```
rc/export_data/plantuml_get_package.py:69: error: Library stubs not installed for "requests" (or incompatible with Python 3.10)
src/export_data/plantuml_get_package.py:69: note: Hint: "python3 -m pip install types-requests"
src/export_data/plantuml_get_package.py:69: note: (or run "mypy --install-types" to install all missing stub packages)
src/export_data/plantuml_get_package.py:69: note: See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#missing-imports
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 24 source files)
```

The default solution is given in the error message:

```
mypy --install-types
```

However, the requirement is already satisfied:

```
Installing missing stub packages:
/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install types-requests

Install? [yN] y

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: types-requests in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (2.25)
```

### Conda Yaml

This would suggest it may be installed on the device, but not in the conda environment, however, it should be, because the following conda environment is created successfully (last 2 lines):

```
# run: conda env create --file environment.yml
# include new packages: conda env update --file environment.yml
name: someenvironment
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - conda
dependencies:
# Specify specific python version.
- python=3.10
- anaconda
- nb_conda
- conda:
# Run python tests.
  - pytest=6.1.2
# Convert notebooks to pdf.
  - nbconvert
  - matplotlib
# Support notebooks.
  - nb_conda
# Visualise graphs for PlantUML
  - graphviz
# Run graph software quickly
  - networkx
- pip
- pip:
# Compile pdf from python.
  - pdflatex
# Write unit tests on Jupyter notebooks.
  - testbook
# Auto generate docstrings
  - pyment
# Auto generate documentation.
  - pdoc3
# Code formatting compliance
  - black
# Generate diagrams.
  - plantuml
# Identify and remove dead code.
  - vulture
# Get PlantUML .jar file.
  - requests
  - types-requests
```

### Question

So I was wondering, how can I ensure the `mypy` recognizes the `types-requests` package in the environment?

Comment: Yes, in the sense that including the `additional_dependencies` resolved the issue. Thank you for the reference.

Comment: yep -- I'm the pre-commit author -- if that dupe solves your problem please accept it as the question author

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A solution was found in [this discussion](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/10632#issuecomment-1017831807)
Changing the `mypy` entry in the `.pre-commit-config.yaml` to:

```
# Test if the variable typing is correct. (Variable typing is when you say:
# def is_larger(nr: int) -> bool: instead of def is_larger(nr). It makes
# it explicit what type of input and output a function has.
 - repo: https://github.com/pre-commit/mirrors-mypy
   rev: v0.950
   hooks:
    - id: mypy
      verbose: true
      args: [--show-error-codes]
      additional_dependencies: ['types-requests']
```

Which yielded output:

```
mypy.....................................................................Passed
- hook id: mypy
- duration: 1.3s

Success: no issues found in 24 source files
```

Comment: Thanks from the bottom of my heart :)

Comment: Thanks I was having an endless argument with ChatGPT about fixing this issue and it wasn't being helpful - back to good 'ole SO